# NuGet release channels

Tags: nuget, build-automation

I am currently designing an automated build environment for releasing of various NuGet packages for my organisation.

As it stands, I want to be able to produce various "levels" of stability for NuGet releases, starting with triggered (i.e: builds made by POST hooks on the `develop` branch) as a replacement for nightlies, followed by source promoted to alpha/beta, RC then "stable" packages.

NuGet has stable and prerelease options for package retrieval, however, prerelease cannot distinguish between different prerelease stages, such as `1.2.3-beta123` and `1.2.3-alpha123` etc.

Is there any way to allow package consumers to select the "lowest" level of stability they would like to subscribe to? AFAIK, the only solution is to create different feeds that are selectively published to during the build process, then work from there. Refer to something like the Xamarin Studio Update setting below;

[image: Xamarin Studio release dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that is built in to NuGet. NuGet separates NuGet packages by their source.

Some teams publish nightly builds to MyGet and only publish official release NuGet package builds to nuget.org but that is just a split of pre-release from release which you could do on one package source.